# Is it possible to get access / refresh tokens from Azure Active Directory (AAD) without logging in through browser?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

For an email account of my organization, we must perform some post-processing of the emails that arrive at the inbox through a cron. Is it possible to perform the authentication flow from a cron without having to enter the credentials in the browser?

What kind of application should it be (single-tenant, multi-tenant, etc.)? What kind of permissions should it have? What authentication flow should I use (client credentials, authorization code, etc)? Can it be done through Python's MSAL?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would suggest you to use either `logic apps` or `power automate` to get `email` instead of getting the `token` from graph-api and handle that yourself.

Comment: I know there are other options, but from what I know they are paid. Based on what I understand from the MSAL README (https://msal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), it should be possible: "[...] There are also daemon apps. In these scenarios, applications acquire tokens on behalf of themselves with no user. " But the documentation doesn't seem to explain how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the SO reference,

We do have a code to getAccessToken() that successfully returns an access token

```html
private String getUserNamesFromGraph() throws Exception {
      String bearerToken = "Bearer "+getAccessToken();
      String url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users";
      String returnData = null;

      try {
        URL apiURL = new URL(url);
        URLConnection con = apiURL.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", bearerToken);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

        returnData = response.toString();
        System.out.println(returnData);

      } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }

      return returnData;
  }

private String getAccessToken() throws Exception {
    String url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "eTarget API");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        String urlParameters = "client_id=*** 
APPLICATION ID FROM APPLICATION REGISTRATION PORTAL ***&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=*** 
APPLICATION SECRET FROM APPLICATION REGISTRATION PORTAL ***&grant_type=client_credentials";
        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
    String returnData = response.toString();
        System.out.println(returnData);

    Map jsonTokenData = new Gson().fromJson(returnData, Map.class);
    String accessToken = (String)jsonTokenData.get("access_token");
    //System.out.println(accessToken);

    return accessToken;
    }
```

Permissions:

1. The application to read the users it has to have an explicitly granted User.Read.All application permission along with admin consent.
2. A daemon application without user interaction, you have to look at the **application permissions** and not **delegated permissions**.
3. Post all changes, you may use  https://jwt.ms to check your access token

SO Reference:  java - Microsoft Graph 401 Unauthorized with access token - Stack Overflow